# Boostrap Carousel not appearing in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm attempting to use a basic Bootstrap carousel in my Rails app and I've copied it over as is:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is currently on a partial page, but I have also tried using the carousel in different HTML pages but to no effect. I also tried using the line of javascript offered on the Bootstrap site:

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

...but this also made no difference. I was expecting to get something resembling an empty Bootstrap Carousel, but what I get in my page is three failed image icons with 'first slide', 'second slide' and 'third slide' next to them. It looks as though Bootstrap is not working at all, but I have already used it in this app for a Navbar and a Jumbotron, which were both successful.

This may be something quite simple, but I'm unable to find out what the problem is, so I would really appreciate some help :-)

Comment: how is your application.css? Did you follow some tutorial to put the bootstrap in your project?

Comment: Bootstrap is running fine as far as I'm aware, nor is it my first time using it on a rails app. In my application.scss I do the following: *= require_tree ./*= require_self / */ then - import "bootstrap-sprockets"; import "bootstrap"; import "*";